# Ajustar o form inline bootstrap dentro do banner rotativo e ajustar os campos

Tags: css

Tenho um formulário do qual tentei colocar no meio de um banner rotativo, mas ficou dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faria para centralizar no meio do banner e os campos ficassem mais harmônicos dentro da div?

```
<form class="form-inline" style="padding: 10px; width: 870px; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);  margin: 150px 10%; position: absolute; z-index: 9999999999">
    <div align="center"><h1 style="color: #FFF; padding: 10px">Sua casa nova está aqui!</h1></div>

               <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                   <select method="post" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
                     <option>O que deseja?</option>
                     <option>Alugar</option>
                     <option>Lançamentos</option>                                          
                 </select>
               </div>                                    
               <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                 <select method="post" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
                     <option>Qual tipo?</option>
                     <option value="Todos" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; font-weight: bold">Todos</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Todos os imóveis</option>
                     <option value="Todos" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; font-weight: bold">  Residencial</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Apartamento padrão</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Casa de condomínio</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Casa de vila</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Casa padrão</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Cobertura</option>                                                             
                 </select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                 <select method="post" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
                     <option>Localização</option>
                     <option>Botafogo</option>
                     <option>Ipanema</option>
                     <option>Copacabana</option>                                          
                 </select>
               </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Buscar</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "mais harmônico"?

Comment: Olá David. Onde está o formulário, parece que ele não está ajustado dentro da div. Gostaria que ele ficasse dentro da div de forma mais centralizada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que o `<form>` está com posicionamento absoluto não é possível de centrar com `margin: 150px auto`. Em vez disso pode aplicar `left:50%` e de seguida puxar para a esquerda em metade do tamanho do elemento com `margin-left: -435px;`.

Assim:

```
<form class="form-inline" style="padding: 10px; width: 870px; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);  margin-top: 150px;margin-left:-435px;left:50%; position: absolute; z-index: 9999999999">
```

Ou tentando visualizar de uma forma mais clara:

```
padding: 10px; 
width: 870px; 
background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);  
margin-top: 150px; /*alterado*/
margin-left:-435px; /*novo*/
left:50%; /*novo*/
position: absolute; 
z-index: 9999999999;
```

Repare que também troquei o `margin` que estava para ficar só `margin-top`.
Quanto ao espaçamento dos elementos é só aplicar `margin` e `padding` necessários para ficarem mais ou menos espaçados entre si até acertar ao seu gosto.

Comment: Obrigado Isac. Funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Assim fica mais apresentável e harmônico:

Em vez de definir uma largura fixa para o `<form>` pq isso vai quebrar a função do Bootstrap em layouts responsivos (quando a tela for menor que o valor definido), basta omitir o `width` e centralizar com `transform`, mantendo o left em 50%:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0); -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0); transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

Ficaria assim:

```
<form class="form-inline" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);  margin-top: 150px;position: absolute; z-index: 9999999999;-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0); -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0); transform: translate(-50%, 0); left: 50%;">
```

Já o `H1`, para não deixar muito espaço sobre o texto principal, você coloca:

```
padding:0 0 20px 0; margin: 0;
```

Ficando assim:

```
<h1 style="color: #FFF;padding:0 0 20px 0; margin: 0px;">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cinebsb.tempsite.ws/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);  margin-top: 150px;position: absolute; z-index: 9999999999;-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0); -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0); transform: translate(-50%, 0); left: 50%;">
    <div><h1 style="color: #FFF;padding:0 0 20px 0; margin: 0px;">Sua casa nova está aqui!</h1></div>

               <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                   <select method="post" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
                     <option>O que deseja?</option>
                     <option>Alugar</option>
                     <option>Lançamentos</option>                                          
                 </select>
               </div>                                    
               <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                 <select method="post" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
                     <option>Qual tipo?</option>
                     <option value="Todos" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; font-weight: bold">Todos</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Todos os imóveis</option>
                     <option value="Todos" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; font-weight: bold">  Residencial</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Apartamento padrão</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Casa de condomínio</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Casa de vila</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Casa padrão</option>
                     <option value="Todos">  - Cobertura</option>                                                             
                 </select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                 <select method="post" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">
                     <option>Localização</option>
                     <option>Botafogo</option>
                     <option>Ipanema</option>
                     <option>Copacabana</option>                                          
                 </select>
               </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Buscar</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado David Samm.